# Does anyone know the ids or class of the fields in django-two-factor-auth forms?

Tags: python, html, django, sass

I am using the django-two-factor-auth package, and the problem is I have not been able to identify either the ids or class of the fields in the included wizard forms. I have tried #id_username and #id_password, but my styling does not apply. I thought these would be the ids because I believe the form inherits from AuthenticationForm. I have also tried a variety of others including #username, #password; #id_username_field, #id_password_field, and #username_field, #password_field. Maybe it's something else I am overlooking. Does anyone know how to call on these fields for styling with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the "**Inspector Tool**" in your browser? By doing so, you can then see what the actual id and/or class is applied to the certain form element in the DOM.

**Chrome**:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

**Firefox**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_HTML

**Safari**:
https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

**Edge**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/elements

If, for whatever reason, you are already in fact referencing the correct class/id, then perhaps your styles are not taking precedence. At that point, seeing some code would help to pin-point the issue.

Comment: Awesome, @EdwardM. Inspect element is what did it. For anyone interested the ids were #id_auth-username, #id_auth-password. Such a simple solution, but I forgot to use inspect element and wasted time sifting through .py files for the correct ids. Thank you, I appreciate your help.